# refresh map in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

its been a while, I am trying angular google maps, i have created the map successfully, but refreshing the map is not working out.. don't know why, i have given refresh in homectrl

> 1. i have created a home page where user enters a place where he wants to see in map.when user clicks submit button, it will go to the next page.
> 2. map page receive the name which user enter and shows in the text box in map view, First i have initialized the map, when user click the view button for this input, the map is shown for searched place.the code is in perfect working condition, but when i refresh the map is not displayed and get initialized..??

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ngMaterial', 'ngCordova', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/map:companyName', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
      controller: 'mapCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    })
});

app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location','$route',
  function($scope, $location,$route) {
    $scope.save = function(companyName) {
      $location.path('/map' + companyName);
    };
    $scope.refresh = function() {
      $route.reload();
    }
  }
]);
app.service('Map', function($q) {
  this.init = function() {
    var options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.00594130000002),
      zoom: 13,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"), options
    );
    this.places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
  }
  this.search = function(str) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    this.places.textSearch({
      query: str
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        d.resolve(results[0]);
      } else d.reject(status);
    });
    return d.promise;
  }
  this.addMarker = function(res) {
    if (this.marker) this.marker.setMap(null);
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: res.geometry.location,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    this.map.setCenter(res.geometry.location);
  }
});

app.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, Map) {
  $scope.place = {};
  console.log($routeParams.companyName);
  $scope.searchPlace = $routeParams.companyName;
  $scope.search = function() {
    $scope.apiError = false;
    Map.search($scope.searchPlace)
      .then(
        function(res) { // success
          console.log("res: " + res);
          Map.addMarker(res);
          $scope.place.name = res.name;
          $scope.place.lat = res.geometry.location.lat();
          $scope.place.lng = res.geometry.location.lng();
        },
        function(status) { // error
          $scope.apiError = true;
          $scope.apiStatus = status;
        }
      );
  }
  Map.init();
});
```

```css
#map { 
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}/* Empty. Add your own CSS if you like */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title> Map Home</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="js/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <md-toolbar style="position:fixed !important;" layout="row">
    <md-button aria-label="refresh" ng-click="refresh()">
      <ng-md-icon icon="refresh"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </md-toolbar>
  <div style="padding-top:56px !important;" ng-view></div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/home.html">
  <div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Company name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="companyName">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <md-button class="md-primary" type="button" ng-click="save(companyName)">
    <label>Viewplace</label>
  </md-button>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/map.html">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <form name="searchForm" novalidate ng-submit="search()">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input ng-bind="searchPlace" name="place" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchPlace" required autofocus />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">View Place</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <form name="resForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate ng-submit="send()">
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please Help me guys, Thank for the help in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For the Support Guys, I have used the location.path('/map') and inside i have given map.init() function to initialize map in $scope.refresh() and This refreshs the map that is what i needed anyways.. :) thanks alex for your time Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $route.reload for the refresh function.
Try Using:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});//second parameter is for $stateParams
```

Apparantly, `$route.reload()` only reinitializes the controller not the services. `$window.location.reload();` reinitializes the services as well. But, using the `$window.location.reload();` refreshes the browser itself which may not be the good solution.

However, with the `$route.reload()`, you can try:

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$route.reload();
```

Templates are cached.If this is the way you want to follow, then you need to remove the template from the $templateCache before you call reload.

Comment: Thank you alex :) i will check, I have doubt that  this one change will initialize the map when i refresh ah alex..?

Comment: sure, most of the time the problem occurs because of the advantage of SPA whereby the controller is initialized only once, so it must get your process working.

Comment: do upvote and mark it as correct if it gets your project working :)

Comment: hi alex, this error occurs..Error: Cannot transition to abstract state '[object Object]'

Comment: this error must have occurred before refreshing in the parent page. what $state.go($state.current,{},{reload:true}); does is just reload your current page with the available scope objects. Here is link to a github project with ionic and geolocation https://github.com/Govinda-Wagle/Ionic-GeoLocation/  if it helps you. In ionic, using ionicView.beforeenter solves the case for reinitialization of the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103459/discussion-between-alex-rumba-and-om-bala).